# Base64 implementation in C#

Tags: c#, performance, base64

I've written the following unsafe C# method to convert a byte array to Base64 encoding.  It works, but it runs at a significantly slower rate than the built-in `Convert.ToBase64String` method.

```
public static unsafe string From(byte[] data)
    {
        int div = data.Length / 3;
        int mod = data.Length % 3;
        int length = data.Length;
        int b64Length = div * 4 + (mod == 0 ? 0 : 4);

        int c = 0;
        char[] r = new char[b64Length];
        fixed (char* tblPointer = base64Table)
        fixed (char* rPointer = r)
        fixed (byte* dPointer = data)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < div * 3; i += 3)
            {
                rPointer[c] = tblPointer[(dPointer[i] & 0xfc) >> 2];
                rPointer[c + 1] = tblPointer[((dPointer[i] & 0x03) << 4) | ((dPointer[i + 1] & 0xf0) >> 4)];
                rPointer[c + 2] = tblPointer[((dPointer[i + 1] & 0x0f) << 2) | ((dPointer[i + 2] & 0xc0) >> 6)];
                rPointer[c + 3] = tblPointer[((dPointer[i + 2]) & 0x3f)];
                c += 4;
            }
            switch (mod)
            {
                case 1:
                    rPointer[c] = tblPointer[(dPointer[length - 1] & 0xfc) >> 2];
                    rPointer[c + 1] = tblPointer[((dPointer[length - 1] & 0x03) << 4)];
                    rPointer[c + 2] = '=';
                    rPointer[c + 3] = '=';
                    c += 4;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    rPointer[c] = tblPointer[(dPointer[length - 2] & 0xfc) >> 2];
                    rPointer[c + 1] = tblPointer[((dPointer[length - 2] & 0x03) << 4) | ((dPointer[length - 1] & 0xf0) >> 4)];
                    rPointer[c + 2] = tblPointer[((dPointer[length - 1] & 0x0f) << 2)];
                    rPointer[c + 3] = '=';
                    c += 4;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return new string(r);
    }
```

I looked at the [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,f9e5bd7b69c5f334) for the .NET method and found that my code is very very similar already.  Is there something I'm missing or is there some sort of optimization to the built in method I don't know about?

The variable `base64Table` in the code is simply a `char[]` with the relevant base64 characters.

The results being **31 Ticks** for the built in method and **2230 Ticks** for my method, measured with the `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class.

Comment: Are you timing it in Debug or Release mode, and are you timing it on Any CPU, x86 or x64?

Comment: @EBrown Ahh I didn't even think of that!  Was testing in Debug on Any CPU.  I should try Release on 64 bit yes?

Comment: If you have a 64-bit system, yes. Release -> x64 -> Build -> Open Folder -> Run. Then, for a proper benchmark, you should *consider* a benchmark tool (Google BenchmarkDotNet), but what you should do is loop, say 10 times on each, discard the first 10 loop results, then loop 10 more times, then take the averages for your comparison. (Right now you're *likely* also measuring JIT on your code.)

Comment: @EBrown Hmmmm just tested and the performance gap is about the same, if anything, worse.

Comment: @EBrown Just read your edit.  I tried the looping and discarding and you were right, they perform about the same.  If you want to write an answer I can mark it as correct.

Comment: I'll write an answer after I actually review the code. :) You're not getting away that easily.

Comment: Not C# but should be similar, because Java also uses JIT. [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/995714). There are also a lot of results on Google for benchmarking JITted binary http://mattwarren.org/2014/09/19/the-art-of-benchmarking/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First and foremost: testing in Debug - Any CPU mode is bad. Debug configurations have *a lot* of extra overhead and <strike>*Any CPU is a non-native instruction configuration**, **both**</strike> will cause you to get poor measurements.

Next, when you do your testing you should *consider* (I say consider because when doing simple comparisons you don't *need* to, but when trying to prove something you should definitely do so) using a proper benchmark tool like BenchmarkDotNet. (It's in NuGet so it's simple to install.)

However, if you choose not to (I'm not going to judge you for that) you should not measure the first execution of your code. You should loop it a few times (I usually use 10-128, depending on how fast the code is) and then discard those results, then **do it again** and keep those results. Take the average as your metric.

### Why?

The first time you execute your code, the JITter (Just-In Time optimizer) will optimize your code *another time*. This adds a substantial amount of overhead to the first execution. *Sometimes a lot of it.* This can (and will) skew your results **substantially**.

* This is heavily debated and may or may not have any effect. In some testing in my environment **x64 is faster**, and in some testing **Any CPU is faster**.

---

Now that the lecture is over, let's look over the code quick:

You have a lot of "magic numbers" here, most notably `4` and `3`, you should consider giving them a `const` identifier. (Consider what `4` and `3` mean in each instance, and what they mean if you were to be writing a Base32 converter instead of Base64.)

Your for loop (`for (int i = 0; i < div * 3; i += 3)`) can use `length` instead of `div * 3` there, just as well you should assign `length` first, then use it instead of `data.Length` **everywhere**. I.e.:

```
    int div = data.Length / 3;
    int mod = data.Length % 3;
```

Should instead be:

```
    int div = length / 3;
    int mod = length % 3;
```

With as frequently as you use `dPointer[length - 1]` and `dPointer[length - 2]`, you should consider extracting variables there for extra micro-performance boosts.

Those are the only complaints I have, good work!

Comment: +1 One thing though: Storing things in variables (`div * 3`, `length`, `dPointer[length - 1]` won't improve performance. While a naive compilation would pointlessly repeat things like array range checks, in practice the compiler will certainly eliminate common subexpressions if they're worth eliminating. Readability should be the OP's main concern here.

Comment: Do you have anything to back up your claim, that AnyCPU has an impact on performance?

Comment: @linac good point, [What does AnyCPU mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516730/what-does-the-visual-studio-any-cpu-target-mean). Looks unlikely that it has any performance implications.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure your reasoning, about why running the code twice is required, is correct. The JITter [doesn't save state](http://kb4dev.com/tutorial/.net-framework-concepts-and-tools/compilation-and-execution-process-in-.net) between runs. Here's a question about [why the second run is faster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295622/where-is-the-net-jit-compiled-code-cached): the Dlls you spent time loading the first time are in the file system cache.

Comment: @NathanCooper I think he meant running the function multiple times (and only timing later runs), not the entire program. So program starts, calls function 10 times in a loop to let the JITter do its thing, then does the timed run afterwards. The JITter only loses state if you exit the program.

Comment: @Bob Sure, never mind then.

Comment: @linac Based on some experimentation I just did, it *looks* like `Any CPU` vs. `x64` doesn't have any sort of noticeable impact, and `Any CPU` **may**, in fact, be ever-so-slightly faster on one of my test programmes in some cases.

Comment: @NathanCooper See comment above, looks like in some situations `Any CPU` is *faster* than `x64`.